# Craft 3 - After launch

Tags: discussion, craft-3

This is a pretty big question, so **all** input is valuable (even if it's just a passing comment)...

Craft 3 will include some notable architectural changes. For starters, it's built on Yii 2 (whereas all previous versions were built on Yii 1). In theory, this will have a minor (if any) impact on Twig-related questions, or anything concerning best-practices for CP decisions. But the impact on **plugin development** will be significant.

So here's the question...

**How should we distinguish between Craft 3 (and higher) questions, vs Craft 2 (and lower) questions?**

Answer (score 2):

Here is my 2 cents... There are a few routes to go here, but it's mainly about **tagging** (except #3).

**Option #1**

We can tag all Craft 3 questions as "craft-3" moving forward. This is the easiest solution in the *short term*, but may cause more problems in the long run (see below).

**Option #2**

We can try to tag all *existing* plugin dev questions with "craft-2". There are probably hundreds though, so this could take awhile.

**Option #3**

We make some sort of actual note (whether an edit or a comment) to all outdated questions. This would be more obvious than a simple tag. But again, this would need to be applied to hundreds of questions.

**Final thoughts**

Personally, I don't like Option #1. It seems like it's creating a large mess that we'd have to deal with at some point in the future. For example, if Craft 4 is completely compatible with Craft 3 (as Craft 1 & 2 were), then that tag would actually *cause* more confusion than it resolves.

Conversely, Options #2 & #3 seem like an awful lot of work. So really, none of these options seem like a slam dunk.

These are just a few suggestions... I'd love to hear what others think!

Comment: Lindsey, before we start doing this by hand could you please ask a StackExchange Super Moderator if they could do this for us (option 2)?

Comment: @carlcs: Good thinking!

Answer (score 2):

There are (right now) 522 questions tagged `plugin development`, which at the rate things are going will be just a drop in the bucket when Craft 4 comes along.

My vote is for #2 and #3 both - go over the 500+ old questions (gradually), and add a craft-2 tag and a useful comment about how this all would work (or no longer be relevant) in craft-3.

Comment: Plus you'd probably get some "super editor" gold badge for doing all the edits!