# Craft 3 - Before launch

Tags: discussion, craft-3

I just wrote this post about what to do with Craft 3 questions [after launch...](https://craftcms.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123/craft-3-after-launch) This thread is about how we should handle Craft 3 questions **before launch**.

For starters, what is "launch"? Are we talking about the **Beta** launch, when it will be considered roughly stable and feature complete? Or are we talking about **post-Beta** launch, when everyone will be actively encouraged to upgrade?

Regardless of how we're defining "launch", let's establish some protocol for handling Craft 3 questions **right now**.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, Craft 3 questions do not yet belong on Stack Exchange.

The current status of Craft 3 is "developer preview"... this is *not* beta. In it's current state, anything is capable of changing, and a relatively high volume of bugs are still waiting to be discovered. It seems that clouding Stack Exchange with Craft 3 questions at this point would actually be detrimental to the overall quality of information to be found here.

Just my 2 cents, curious to hear the opinions of others.

---

**UPDATE (May 1, 2017) - RE: Simon's comment below**

Even at this point, I think I'd stick with my original answer. Craft 3 will be in beta for another 4-6 months or more, so I certainly wouldn't call it "ready for prime time". The best (and most active) place to ask for help seems to be the #craft3 channel on Slack.

Why do I recommend Slack instead? Since Craft 3 is still actively evolving, it's very possible for questions to morph into feature requests and bug reports. Saying "how do I do this" on Slack may lead to P&T saying "let me tweak Craft to make that possible/easier". That kind of conversation is obviously a much better fit for Slack than SE.

Lastly, it's worth noting that P&T are still discouraging people from using Craft 3 on a production site. If it's not ready for the general public, it's probably not ready to start discussing here.

Comment: I agree... would be lots of noise at this point in time.

Comment: honestly disagree. I didn't even know that it was coming out until now so interesting to read about.

Comment: Seeing as Craft 3 is a long time coming, I agree. A public beta is one thing, a developer preview is a completely another.  Saw a user today [post](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/15682/404-error-on-craft-3-installation) about 3, don't know if he's confused or just wants to be bleeding edge. Either way, not helpful to the community IMO.

Comment: Now that it's in beta, would your answer change?

Comment: @SimonEast Hmm, good question... Even at this point, I think I'd stick with my original answer. Craft 3 will be in beta for another 4-6 months or more, so I certainly wouldn't call it "ready for prime time". The best (and most active) place to ask for help seems to be the #craft3 channel on Slack.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a complete answer, but here is one partial answer.

I've begun upgrading several plugins to Craft 3.  In the process, I've begun to run into several errors and questions as I sort out the details of getting things upgraded.  Many of these issues are my misunderstandings and trial and error and would be noise on Stack Exchange.  However, several of the things I'm running into our errors that I expect others will run into as well.

Things like system generated Error Messages and making sense of the syntax updates necessary to get things working on the new platform are relevant to others in the community and if we suppress all related questions during the beta, we delay the timeframe that more people see others using Craft 3 and adopt and share there own knowledge on the topic.

So, I'm for some middle ground. As any question being posted, there should be some discretion from the poster that the question is relevant in the broader picture, but starting to get solutions shared around how to troubleshoot error messages at the very least would be a step in the right direction to help others quickly solve their own issues as they get more involved in Craft 3 development.